# Spring Bean Overriding My ObjectMapper Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, objectmapper

Had an issue today where a dependency wired with a configuration kept winning when it came to some `ObjectMapper` configuration I was trying to do. I added the following to my Spring Boot application.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomObjectMapperConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }

}
```

I'd actually rather not use timestamps, but for backwards compatibility I had to do this. I put a debug point at the line in question here and it got hit, but I kept getting dates returned to me in ISO format, which is the default for most or our projects.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that a company dependency that I was bringing in had the following:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperPropertiesConfig {
    /**
     * @deprecated Spring boot jackson properties should be used instead.
     */
    @Deprecated
    @Autowired
    public void setObjectMapper(
            final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, !ignoreUnknown);
    }
...
```

This class was getting loaded after my class, so it alwasy won with regards to the `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature.

To fix this I ended up adding a `@DependsOn` annotation. This forced the other bean to load first giving my bean the chance to win the configuration war. Finding the correct name of the bean was difficult. It ended up looking something like this:

```
@DependsOn("path.to.object.ObjectMapperPropertiesConfig")
```

Note: The `@Deprecated` annotation here tell me that this code will be going away in future versions in favor of spring boot properties anyway. For now, my change will work.